# python only search through files that were open before a specific date

Tags: python, time

I running a script through multiple network drives for some cleanup which is not necessary to mention here. The script runs a long time and I want to reduce it by having it only open/do the cleaning on files that were last opened during a time period. I only want to look at files that were last opened from 2014 up and including 2017. 
this line prints out

```
print time.ctime(os.stat(r'R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\MXDs\conservation_priority.mxd').st_atime)
```

`Fri Nov 17 14:48:12 2017`

how do I an IF statement that will only search for files that were last opened from 2014-2017.

Comment: So, you are just wanting to see what an IF statement would look like given your resulting string, and check if it is between 2014 and 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the date string to find the year.

```
file_name = 'R:\Data\LUCZ_2017\MXDs\conservation_priority.mxd'
time_str = time.ctime(os.stat(file_name).st_atime)
year = int(time_str[-4:])
if year >= 2014 and year <= 2017:
    print('I was opened between 2014 and 2017')
```

Comment: okay yes this will work, but now I realized I posted a hard coded example into this..how would you insert a variable into the path that contains the file?

Comment: What do you mean? What are you expecting from `os.stat`? I've updated the answer to show using a variable but I assume you knew how to do that already?